# Difference between String and String[]

Tags: java, android, string

I am trying to add the strings to a csv file in Android. As per the syntax it is asking to add `String []` but I have added below line

```
String [] s1;    
s1=c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Sname"));
```

retrieving the value from cursot and storing it in `s1`. Above line giving me the error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to String[]
```

What is the difference between `String and String[]`, and how can I convert to `String[]`?

I am a beginner to Android and Java.

### Edit

I was able to store but unable to store in `writeline` of csv class.

```
CSVWriter export=new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("/sdcard/"+stock+".csv"));
export.writeAll(s1, true);
```

error:

```
The method writeAll(List<String[]>, boolean) in the type
CSVWriter is not applicable for the arguments (String[], boolean)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String is a single String object String[] is an array of String objects.  The problem is you are trying to add a String Object to a String array without specifying an index.

You could do something like:

```
String [] s1 = new String[1];    
s1[0]=c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Sname"));
```

Just an example or you could just create a String Object instead of a String array:

```
String s1;    
s1=c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Sname"));
```

Basically if you want to use an array you must specify an index of that array to Store the object because there are multiple objects stored in the array each one has its own index.

Try doing this:

```
ArrayList<String[]> csvExport = new ArrayList<String[]>();
csvExport.add(s1);
CSVWriter export=new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("/sdcard/"+stock+".csv"));
export.writeAll(csvExport, true);
```

This will only add one line to your csv file. If you want multiple lines you will need to create multiple String[] and add each String[] to your ArrayList csvExport.

Think of a String[] array as your columns for example:

```
String[] columnNames = new String[2];

columnNames[0] = "ID";
columnNames[1] = "Name";

String[] person1 = new String[2];

person1[0] = "1";
person1[1] = "George";

ArrayList<String[]> csvExport = new ArrayList<String[]>();
csvExport.add(columnNames);
csvExport.add(person1);
CSVWriter export=new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("/sdcard/"+stock+".csv"));
export.writeAll(csvExport, true);
```

The code above would give you a csv file like this:

ID          Name

1            George

Comment: Thanks for your response... but how can I store data in string array when I checked option there is no method to add.. can you please elaborate

Comment: Thanks now I am able to store in String[] but getting one more issue... updated my question... can you please help..

Comment: @Siva I added some more explanation look at the new code and see if you understand how the CSVWriter is working.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to assign a String to an array of String objects, which will not work. You can declare a String like so:

```
String str = c1.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Sname"));
```

Or you can assign the String to an index in the array of String objects like so, and this will work, but I don't see a reason to use an array here.

```
String [] strArray = new String[5]; // String array of length 5

strArray[0] = c1.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Sname")); // set the first element in the array to reference a String object
```